# Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:default [[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)]

Tags: windows, ssl, python-3.6, discord.py

I'm trying to solve this issue I am currently having. I really don't understand the error itself and I've been to multiple forms researching and trying to get this resolved but to no avail.

Any feedback and help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Platform**: Windows 10

**Python**: Python3.6.8

**Intention**:  Trying to run a discord bot application.

**Result**: I get this certification error which won't allow the program to connect to discord.

**Note**: The bot can for some reason run without a problem on my other windows 10 computer.

**Error Log**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\Desktop\AyStar\Oracle(V6).py", line 360, in <module>
    client.run("TOKEN")
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 261, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 165, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 483, in _request
    timeout=real_timeout
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 859, in _create_connection
    req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1004, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 986, in _create_direct_connection
    req=req, client_error=client_error)
  File "C:\Users\oiabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 941, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise ClientConnectorSSLError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorSSLError: Cannot connect to host discordapp.com:443 ssl:default [[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to cancel ssl verify

```py
import asyncio
import sys
import pymysql.cursors
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from aiohttp import TCPConnector





async def postmsg(url,msg):
    async with ClientSession(connector=TCPConnector(verify_ssl=False)) as session:
        # data={"msgtype":"text","text":{"content":msg},"at":{"atMobiles":["17633919216"],"isAtAll":"false"}}
        async with session.post(url,data=json.dumps(msg),headers=headers) as response:
            response = await response.read()
            # print(response)
            return  response
```